# Apex Managed Sharing trigger stopped working when changed field from Lookup to Master-Detail

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have two custom objects, listing and transaction.  Initially I had a Lookup field on the transaction object to the listing object.  I had Apex Managed Sharing set up to share the transaction with several user lookup fields on the related listing object.  It was working perfectly.

I changed the field type of the listing field on the transaction object to Master-Detail and now I get the following error every time I try to save a new transaction:

"TransactionApexSharing: execution of AfterInsert caused by: line 1, column 1: trigger body is invalid and failed recompilation: Entity is not org-accessible"

Transaction and Listing objects are both set to Private and I can't find any typos in the code.  The trigger hasn't been changed since it was working with the Lookup field.

Here is my code:

```
trigger TransactionApexSharing on Transaction__c (after insert, after update) {

if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){



    Set<id> triggerIds = trigger.newMap.keyset();

    List<Transaction__c> listWithParentData = [select Listing__r.Listing_Agent_1__r.id, Listing__r.Listing_Agent_2__r.id, Listing__r.Listing_Agent_3__r.id from Transaction__c where id in :triggerIds];


    List<Transaction__Share> tranShrs = new List<Transaction__Share>();

    Transaction__Share laShr;
    Transaction__Share la2Shr;
    Transaction__Share la3Shr;
    Transaction__Share saShr;
    Transaction__Share sa2Shr;
    Transaction__Share sa3Shr;


    for(Transaction__c atransaction : listWithParentData){

        laShr = new Transaction__Share();
        la2Shr = new Transaction__Share();
        la3Shr = new Transaction__Share();

        laShr.ParentId = atransaction.Id;
        la2Shr.ParentId = atransaction.Id;
        la3Shr.ParentId = atransaction.Id;

        if (atransaction.Listing__r.Listing_Agent_1__c != null)
        {
            // Set the ID of user or group being granted access 
            laShr.UserOrGroupId = atransaction.Listing__r.Listing_Agent_1__c;
            // Set the access level 
            laShr.AccessLevel = 'edit';
            // Set the Apex sharing reason 
            laShr.RowCause = Schema.Transaction__Share.RowCause.Share_Transaction_with_Agency_Agents__c;
            // Add objects to list for insert 
            tranShrs.add(laShr);
        }

        if (atransaction.Listing__r.Listing_Agent_2__c != null)
        {
            la2Shr.UserOrGroupId = atransaction.Listing__r.Listing_Agent_2__c;
            la2Shr.AccessLevel = 'edit';
            la2Shr.RowCause = Schema.Transaction__Share.RowCause.Share_Transaction_with_Agency_Agents__c;
            tranShrs.add(la2Shr);
        }

        if (atransaction.Listing__r.Listing_Agent_3__c != null)
        {
            la3Shr.UserOrGroupId = atransaction.Listing__r.Listing_Agent_3__c;
            la3Shr.AccessLevel = 'edit';
            la3Shr.RowCause = Schema.Transaction__Share.RowCause.Share_Transaction_with_Agency_Agents__c;
            tranShrs.add(la3Shr);
        }

    }

    for(Transaction__c mytransaction : trigger.new){
        // Instantiate the sharing objects 

        saShr = new Transaction__Share();
        sa2Shr = new Transaction__Share();
        sa3Shr = new Transaction__Share();

        // Set the ID of record being shared 


        saShr.ParentId = mytransaction.Id;
        sa2Shr.ParentId = mytransaction.Id;
        sa3Shr.ParentId = mytransaction.Id;


        if (mytransaction.Selling_Agent_1_User__c != null)
        {
            saShr.UserOrGroupId = mytransaction.Selling_Agent_1_User__c;
            saShr.AccessLevel = 'edit';
            saShr.RowCause = Schema.Transaction__Share.RowCause.Share_Transaction_with_Agency_Agents__c;
            tranShrs.add(saShr);
        }

        if (mytransaction.Selling_Agent_2_User__c != null)
        {
            sa2Shr.UserOrGroupId = mytransaction.Selling_Agent_2_User__c;
            sa2Shr.AccessLevel = 'edit';
            sa2Shr.RowCause = Schema.Transaction__Share.RowCause.Share_Transaction_with_Agency_Agents__c;
            tranShrs.add(sa2Shr);
        }

        if (mytransaction.Selling_Agent_3_User__c != null)
        {
            sa3Shr.UserOrGroupId = mytransaction.Selling_Agent_3_User__c;
            sa3Shr.AccessLevel = 'edit';
            sa3Shr.RowCause = Schema.Transaction__Share.RowCause.Share_Transaction_with_Agency_Agents__c;
            tranShrs.add(sa3Shr);
        }



    }

    // Insert sharing records and capture save result  

    // The false parameter allows for partial processing if multiple records are passed  

    // into the operation  

    Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(tranShrs,false);

    // Create counter 

    Integer i=0;

    // Process the save results 

    for(Database.SaveResult sr : lsr){
        if(!sr.isSuccess()){
            // Get the first save result error 

            Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0];

            // Check if the error is related to a trivial access level 

            // Access levels equal or more permissive than the object's default  

            // access level are not allowed.  

            // These sharing records are not required and thus an insert exception is  

            // acceptable.  

            if(!(err.getStatusCode() == StatusCode.FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION  
                                           &&  err.getMessage().contains('AccessLevel'))){
                // Throw an error when the error is not related to trivial access level. 

                trigger.newMap.get(tranShrs[i].ParentId).
                  addError(
                   'Unable to grant sharing access due to following exception: '
                   + err.getMessage());
            }
        }
        i++;
    } 
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you flip the relationship from lookup to master detail a lot changes.
You lose fine grained access to details, that's it. Whatever rights user has to the master - he has them for the details as well (OK, excluding stuff like 'Read/Create/Edit/Delete' which is in Profiles, I'm talking about access to particular record, not general rights).

1. On the detail "OwnerId" will disappear (can't be queried, described etc)
2. Which has some finer points if you ever:

   - need approval process on detail and suddenly you can't use queues, you need to specify users directly.
   - users ask "what happened to My Transactions" in list views or reports
3. Last but not least - **Detail__Share table disappears** as well.

Try editing your trigger in the sandbox (just add 1 space or something), it will probably complain that there's no such table `Transaction_Share`.

You can either make sure that Agents have edit rights to parent listing (but that means they can edit ANY related transaction) and ditch the trigger or undo the M-D. It's really a case of going back to your users and asking for business logic ;)

Why did you flip it to M-D? Cascade delete, rollups etc. could be done with a bit of code if it turns out you can't afford losing this fine-grained edit access to each transaction.

But after a quick look at your code it seems to me you'll be fine with controlling the access on Listing level and not on the details?